# Git SVN error: a Git process crashed in the repository earlier

Tags: git, git-svn

I was just trying to commit changes to the Git master. From what I have read, it seems that the idea is to delete the lock file. The message says:

> make sure no other Git processes are running and remove the file manually

Perhaps someone knows, which file to remove and how to remove?

Comment: Could you show the full error message including the command you're running?

Comment: i use the tortoise though. can you delete that file in the tortoise or only in the shell?

Comment: You'll probably have to do it in a shell or file explorer.  You may have to show hidden files.

Comment: full error is this: fatal: Unable to create 'C/etc/.git/index.lock' file exists. If no other git process is currently runnning, this probably means a git process crashed in the repository earlier. Make sure no other git process is running and remove the file manually to continue.

Comment: The error message says it all.  Delete `C:\etc\.git\index.lock` like any other file.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

The file in question is likely `.git/index.lock` and it [should be safe to just remove it if you have no other git processes running](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Recovering-the-index-after-a-git-crash-td2267712.html).  Make sure a git-svn command isn't hanging.

PS  My usual approach to fixing git-svn problems is to make a fresh pull of the repository.  Time consuming, but you can do it in parallel with trying to fix the problem. Have a little race between you and git. Of course, this only works if you didn't have unpushed commits.

Comment: This didn't solve it for me. I had another remaining lock file at .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/index.lock.

Answer (score 83):

> Removing the `index.lock` file like Schwern stated will solve this
>   problem.

You can remove it by running    `rm -f ./.git/index.lock`

The `rm` command is used to remove (delete) files and directories.

The `-f` stands for force which tells your computer to remove the files without prompting for confirmation

Answer (score 9):

For "GUI" user like me

Open Git Extension and choose repository (if more than one)
Choose "Settings" from top menu then "Git Maintenance" and then click on "Delete Index Lock"

Git Extensions: Settings->Git Maintenance->Delete Index Lock

Answer (score 6):

It may also concern any *.lock files in .git/

Check and remove them. You may use: `rm -f ./.git/*.lock`

Answer (score 2):

You have already opened a commit in another tab in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

I solve this error by just following steps:-

1. Go in your same directory in which your project exist.
2. Unhide Hidden files (for ubntu press ctrl+ H)
3. Move inside .git directory
4. Remove "index.lock" file

It solve this Problem

Answer (score 0):

The answer giving by @Joel helped, except that for windows users you may have to enable show hidden files/folders to access **.git** folder where **index.lock** file exist.
[Use this link in case you don't know how to enable hidden folders.](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=27479)

Answer (score 0):

**Removing the index.lock file like Schwern stated will solve this problem.**

You can remove it by running  rm -f ./.git/index.lock

The rm command is used to remove (delete) files and directories.

The -f stands for force which tells your computer to remove the files without prompting for confirmation

still not working means **open the git through git bash instead of doing in terminal**

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue, and I couldn’t even able to find the `index.lock`.
My environment was a little bit different, a cluster with multiple nodes.
The issue was encountered in the master node, and I solve it just by jumping to the worker node since the master node is chaired by all connected user

Answer (score -1):

Just type `.git` Infront of the project path.
For example: `C:\DotNetAngularProject\MyApp\.git`

You will get list of files & folders [list of file names like HEAD,FETCH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImSzj.png)

Delete `index.lock` file manually.

Close your project & restart again.

Issue will be solved.