# Another git process seems to be running and thus cant commit

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I was committing my git process and thought that it would be okay if I ignore comments so I used this code

```
git commit filename
```

Bash was strange and thus i closed the console
now when I use proper command

```
git commit -m"THIRD COMMIT" filename
```

It give the following response:

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:

what should I do?

Comment: Does the error message mention a lock file?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII thanks but method I mentioned is working. And I learned it from youtube. Link is
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_Clau1bYco)
If there is something wrong with the method, do you mind putting some light on the topic.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I met this problem recently too.

```
rm -f ./.git/index.lock
```

try this commend in your git bash, then you can solve your problem.

Comment: In my case I had to use "rm -f ../.git/index.lock"

Comment: I would add to do it in the root folder, where .git is located

Answer (score 8):

Removing the `index.lock` like it was recommended in [this answer of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9185170/3850319) should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried that solution and that is why I am here. I cannot find index.lock anywhere. I did read all related questions on stackoverflow before asking it.

Comment: It does not though.  I can find index.lock file but deleting it does not change anything

Answer (score 4):

1. In windows, change settings to view hidden folders
2. Navigate inside .git folder
3. Manually delete .lock file

Answer (score 2):

This helps to avoid the below message
"Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g. an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process may have crashed in this repository earlier: remove the file manually to continue."

Even in windows when I tried deleting the index.lock file, 
the git reset --hard HEAD command was executing without any hindrance.

> del index.lock
>   git reset --hard HEAD

Previously when I was running the checkout process inside this repository , I had to disconnect in middle of the process. So this might be the cause for this issue.

Comment: you just made my day !

Answer (score 1):

It happened for me when I run pull from GIT command and got conflicts and try to revert them by the TortoiseGIT client.
I resolved this by running below code at root folder level of my repo

```
rm .git/index.lock
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have same faced issues when i tried to staged file in **SourceTree**.

To solve this go to the **.git** folder in the **project directory** and manually delete **index.lock** and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The commands didn't seem to work for me so I navigated to the root folder of my project, viewed hidden files, then navigated to .git/ to delete index.lock, I rerun git commit -m"THIRD COMMIT" filename and that was it!

Answer (score 0):

In case you stopped the rebase before it was finished you can run this command on the git bash on the **.git** folder:

`rm REBASE_HEAD.lock`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i opened Git Bash (on windows) and run this command rm .git/index.lock after can use git add whith normaly

Answer (score -2):

check .gitignore files . When I tried to find the error I found and fixed it.

Comment: There is already an accepted answer. What do you think should be changed in `.gitignore`, and why would it help?

Comment: whitespaces delete in .gitignore file